# How to get rid of brackets when selecting data from SQL table (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
def check_gen0_1(db_name):
    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select JuvPop from History where Generation=0")
    global results1
    results1 = cursor.fetchone() 

def check_gen0_run(db_name):
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_gen0_1(db_name)

def menu2(dbless, db_name):
    check_gen0_run(db_name)
        print(results1)
```

This is my code. The result printed is

```
(0,)
```

How do I get rid of the brackets? How do I only get the 0 or whatever value is there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.fetchone()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) returns a single row of results of the query which is represented as a tuple. If you need the first value from it, just *get it by index*:

```
print(results1[0])
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed this for my course work. Is there a way to only return a single box?

Comment: @NasifRob not sure what you mean, but does not it already return a single `JuvPop` value? Thanks.

Comment: Also, quick unrelated question. How do you select the highest value from a column?

Comment: @NasifRob you can use `max`, for instance: `select max(JuvPop) from History`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if:

```
results1 = results1[1:-2]
print(results1)
```

or just:

```
print(results1[1:-2])
```

would get you what you wanted?  Depends if the output you're getting is a string of course.

This splits the first char and last 2 characters from the results, which is fine if this is something that will happen for every value you're getting but will cause issues if these values are changeable.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Did you try to run it to see if it works before you post it? I kindly ask you to remove your answer.